# Flexslider works in everything but IE 10

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

Flexslider works in every instance but IE 10.  Website is www.nybreeder.com

can someone direct to what is wrong in the coding?

Not sure if its a version error and how to correct, or if its just a hanging code line needing finishing.. my eyes are beginning to hurt.

Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Westchester NY Puppies for Sale </title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="description" content="We offer the finest selection of purebred and        designer puppies in Westchester NY." />
<meta name="publisher" href="https://plus.google.com/104126152754968851553" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" media="screen" />
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/superfish.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.responsivemenu.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.flexslider-min.js"></script>
<script src="js/cufon-yui.js"></script>
<script src="js/KleinSlabserif-Light_300.font.js"></script>
<script src="js/cufon-replace.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.equalheights-rt.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.ui.totop.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function(){
            if (($.browser.msie) && ($.browser.version < '9.0')) {
        $('.flexslider').flexslider({
            animation: "slide",
            slideshow: true,
            slideshowSpeed: 7000,
            animationDuration: 600,
            prevText: "Previous",
            nextText: "Next",
            controlNav: true,
        })   } else {
        $('.flexslider').flexslider({
            animation: "fade",
            slideshow: true,
            slideshowSpeed: 7000,
            animationDuration: 600,
            prevText: "Previous",
            nextText: "Next",
            controlNav: true,
        });  } 
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Did you check your browser's console to see if it throws any errors?

Comment: not sure what you mean, i hardly use IE 10 sorry, I use chrome dev tools, if i view the site in IE 9 works fine, its just IE10

Comment: Yeah, IE 10 (and IE 9 and 8) should have the same thing - a feature called Developer Tools (opened by pressing F12). You should look at the "console" to see if any errors are thrown.

Comment: HTML1508: Unmatched end tag. 
index.html, line 103 character 6
HTML1514: Extra "<body>" tag found. Only one "<body>" tag should exist per document. 
index.html, line 225 character 39
HTML1423: Malformed start tag. Attributes should be separated by whitespace. 
index.html, line 319 character 72
HTML1409: Invalid attribute name character. Attribute names should not contain ("),('),(<), or (=). 
index.html, line 319 character 81

Comment: those are codes thrown, nothing that would seem to effect why slider works in everything but 10

Comment: I am dealing with another "Designers" coding errors in trying to fix this issue, i guess now i will fix the errors too!  But still need help on why everything but IE 10 works.

Comment: Is this right? in your code: "if ($.browser.version < '9.0')"  looks like you are excluding ie 10.  Looks like the if and else are the same... flexslider may not support ie10 properly, which behaves like other browsers.

Comment: what do you think it should be 10.0?

Comment: Tracker1 make it an answer so you get rep

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like the '9.0' shouldn't be in quotes, and should maybe be 10?

```
$(function(){
    if (($.browser.msie) && ($.browser.version < 10)) {
        $('.flexslider').flexslider({
            animation: "slide",
            slideshow: true,
            slideshowSpeed: 7000,
            animationDuration: 600,
            prevText: "Previous",
            nextText: "Next",
            controlNav: true,
        });   
    } else {
        $('.flexslider').flexslider({
            animation: "fade",
            slideshow: true,
            slideshowSpeed: 7000,
            animationDuration: 600,
            prevText: "Previous",
            nextText: "Next",
            controlNav: true,
        });  
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this is my first post in this forum....I was also facing similar problem...got the answer from the following link....

https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/issues/413

Following is the summary from GitHUb...

**i fix it by
add this
slider.container.css("transition-duration", dur);
below
slider.container.css("-" + slider.pfx + "-transition-duration", dur);  //Line 616
and add this
slider.container.css('transform',target);
below
slider.container.css(slider.args); //Line 622**

after adding the code it could give you trouble in chrome...following is my solution to work in all browser...

//line no 609-614

```
               var isChrome = window.chrome;

    if(isChrome) {

    slider.container.css("-" + slider.pfx + "-transition-duration", dur);

    }else{

    slider.container.css("transition-duration", dur);

    }
```

//line no 619-624

```
     var isChrome = window.chrome;

  if(isChrome) {

  if (slider.transitions || dur === undefined) slider.container.css(slider.args);

  }else{

  if (slider.transitions || dur === undefined) slider.container.css('transform',target);

  }
```

Hope it may help!!!

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is trying to debug IE 11 it identifies itself as mozilla:

```
if ( ($.browser.mozilla) && (Math.floor($.browser.version) == 11) ) {
  $('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "fade",
    ...
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same problem - fade animation works in ie9 but not in ie10+.

Fixed with css:

`.flexslider .slides > li {-ms-transition: all 0.8s ease-out;}`